# Add multiple hyperlinks to one Google Sheets Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet with cells that I want to add titles to separated by line breaks, and I would like to add hyperlinks to those titles. I have the links stored in an Apps Script object as key-value pairs, e.g.

```
urls = {link1:"link1.com", link2:"link2.com", ...etc.}
```

Some other info: the titles all have the same number of characters and are separated by newline "\n"
Some cells will have varying numbers of titles, 1 or more.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this via richTextValues and a for-loop but not sure how to programmatically set the link urls for cells with different numbers of links, since it looks like you need to set the richtextvalue and can't modify/append links to it

Example showing correct behavior for one cell with 3 links, but this needs to work for cells with different numbers of links

```
function SetUrls(){
  var links = {"link1" : "link1.com", "link2" : "link2.com", "link3" : "link3.com"};
  let cellToAddLinksTo = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  
  var richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText(cellToAddLinksTo.getValue())
    .setLinkUrl(0, 5, links["link1"])
    .setLinkUrl(5, 10, links["link2"])
    .setLinkUrl(10, 15, links["link3"])
    .build();
  cellToAddLinksTo.setRichTextValue(richValue);
}
```

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDjW7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `I have a spreadsheet with cells that I want to add titles to separated by line breaks, and I would like to add hyperlinks to those titles.`, in your spreadsheet, a cell value has a text including the line breaks.
- You want to give `urls = {link1:"link1.com", link2:"link2.com", ...etc.}` to each line of the current cell value.

  - In this case, you want to give the link of `link1.com` to a text of `link1`, and give the link of `link2.com` to a text of `link2`,,, in the cell.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

```js
function SetUrls() {
  var links = { "link1": "link1.com", "link2": "link2.com", "link3": "link3.com" };
  let cellToAddLinksTo = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();

  // I modified the below script.
  var richValue = cellToAddLinksTo.getRichTextValue().copy();
  var cellValue = cellToAddLinksTo.getDisplayValue();
  var offset = 0;
  cellValue.split("\n").forEach(e => {
    var k = e.trim();
    if (links[k]) {
      richValue.setLinkUrl(offset, offset + e.length, links[k]);
    }
    offset += e.length + 1;
  });
  cellToAddLinksTo.setRichTextValue(richValue.build());
}
```

##### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. In this case, the cell value is checked and the link is set to the value of the key of `links`.

[image]

#### Modified script 2:

```js
function SetUrls2() {
  var links = { "link1": "link1.com", "link2": "link2.com", "link3": "link3.com" };
  let cellToAddLinksTo = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();

  // I modified the below script.
  var keys = ["link1", "link2", "link3"];
  var richValue = cellToAddLinksTo.getRichTextValue().copy();
  var cellValue = cellToAddLinksTo.getDisplayValue();
  var offset = 0;
  cellValue.split("\n").forEach((e, i) => {
    if (links[keys[i]]) {
      richValue.setLinkUrl(offset, offset + e.length, links[keys[i]]);
    }
    offset += e.length + 1;
  });
  cellToAddLinksTo.setRichTextValue(richValue.build());
}
```

##### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. In this case, the cell value is ignored and the links are reflected in order of `var keys = ["link1", "link2", "link3"];`.

[image]

#### References:

- [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)
- [Class RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)

Comment: Works great! Thanks. Side note: it looks like if the links don't contain the url header "https://" there might be a bug with Sheets where if you click the cell to edit the links, they get deleted. Adding the full url header to the urls object fixed that issue for me.

Comment: @albert Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, thank you for your additional information.